# UIPopoverController. Is is appropriate to embed a tableViewController within?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am doing an iPad imaging app and I am considering UIPopoverController as my workhorse user interface element. The user will spend most of their time immersed in fullscreen content (in both portrait and landscape). When the user wants to select a different piece of content I want to use UIPopoverController to handle that. Is it appropriate to embed a tableViewController in a UIPopoverController to allow in-place scrolling or am I abusing the intended use of UIPopoverController?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. You might consider using a split view controller, with the table view embedded in the left-hand view; that, plus a toolbar item to present the popover-enclosed table in portrait mode, is a pretty common design pattern.

Comment: I have seen the split view controller. Is there away to retract the master view so it does not eat up all that lovely screen real estate when in landscape? Cheers.

Comment: Remember, Apple 'requests' that splitviewControllers are loaded as Root View...and not loaded from another view.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine.  You can see lots of examples of Apple apps (eg Mail) that do exactly that.